# Word Sort function incorrect formatting and count

Tags: python, tkinter

I originally created a python word sort function that was meant to record all the words in a txt file and read back while counting the occurence of each word. This program worked correctly, I then sought out to modify this program to count only the top 20 words of a html file and read back the occurrence of only those top 20 words. However after working through the bugs it's not giving me the correct formatting and the correct count. I'm seeking a count that looks like this:

[image]

however my count appears as so:

[image]

and doesn't give the correct count. I've debugged all the errors however I don't understand what's occurring to cause this difference in output.

```
#Imports
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from collections import Counter

#Functions
def countWords(s):
    signos = [',', '.', ';', ':']
    cleanstr = ''
    for letra in s.lower():
        if letra in signos:
            cleanstr += ''
        else:
            cleanstr += letra
    strlist = cleanstr.split(' ')
    return dict(Counter(strlist))


def open_file():
    text = mainWindow.e2.get()

    count = countWords(s)
    myLabel = Label(root, text=open_file)
    myLabel.pack()


#Graphics
fullString = ""
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Count words")
root.geometry('400x400')
root.fileToRead = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="c:/temp/", filetypes=(("HTML File", "*.html"),("All Files","*.*")), title = "choose a file.")
wordCount = {} 
fileName = root.fileToRead.split('/')
fileName = fileName[len(fileName)-1]
label = tk.Label(root, text="Top 20 Words For: " + fileName + '\n' + fullString, foreground="black", font=("Times New Roman", 16))

#Background Image Label
#bg = PhotoImage(file = "./guibackground.gif")

# Show image using label 
#label1 = Label( root, image = bg) 
#label1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER) 


#Class Window
class Window:

     def __init__(self):

        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.btn = tk.Button(text='Open File', command=self.open_file)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn = tk.Button(text='Exit', command=root.quit)
        self.btn.pack()
        self.lbl = tk.Label()
        self.lbl.pack()
        self.root.mainloop()

     def open_file(self):
    
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Select file', filetypes=(('html files','*.html'), ('all files','*.*')))
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.lbl.configure(text=f'{Counter(f.read().split())}')

     def word_count(self):

        sorted_wordCount = sorted(wordCount.items(), key = lambda kv:(kv[1], kv[0]), reverse=True)

        count = 1
        fullString = ""
        for item in sorted_wordCount:
            if count < 20:
                fullString = fullString + str(count) + ": "+ str(item) + '\n'
            elif count == 20:
                fullString = fullString + str(count) + ": " + str(item)
            else:
                break
                count = count + 1
    

        self.button = Button(root, text="Open File", command=open_file)
        self.button.pack()
        self.exit_button = Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.quit)
        self.exit_button.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    mainWindow = Window()

        
    

root.mainloop()
```

I took out the gif image background in order to eliminate the error that would cause.

Comment: It will be more helpful to put there the input and the expected output as text, not screenshot. It will be easier for the others to create the testcase.

Comment: @MarcelPreda I don't have the text for the expected output just the screenshot, i wasn't provided with text in the book, also for some reason my current output doesn't allow me to copy and paste for text, which is another problem I'm having, sorry if this seems difficult

Answer (score 1):

change `self.lbl = tk.Label()` to `self.lbl = tk.Message(self.root)`. then use the following code:

```py
class Window:

    def __init__(self):
      ...

    def open_file(self):
    
        filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir='/', title='Select file', filetypes=(('html files','*.html'), ('all files','*.*')))
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            self.lbl.configure(text=f'{self.formatFun(Counter(f.read().split()).most_common(20))}')


    def formatFun(self, var):
        string = "Top 20 words for: mathbeth.html \n"
        for index, item in enumerate(var, start=1):
            string += f'{index}: {item} \n'
        return string
```

Comment: that fixed the formatting issue however can you help with the count and why isn't it only displaying the top 20 words @JacksonPro